# how to add polygon in bingmaps from localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bing-maps

i was working with bingmap  api with react and my plan is to create a application where user will store the polygon in localstorage and when the user visit the application the polygon should be rendered in the map from getting polygon details from localstorge but i can't render the polygon from localstorge i get weird error

**LOCALSTORAGE**

```
const lands = localStorage.getItem("lands")
const parsed = JSON.parse(lands)
//localStorage
parsed.forEach(function(e){
   var p = new self.Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(e["polygon"],{
    fillColor: "rgba(51,0,255,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "#3300FF",
    strokeThickness: 4
   });
   console.log(p)
   self.map.entities.push(p);
})
```

**CODE**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    var self = this;
    this.loadBingApi("API_KEY").then(_ => {
        self.map = new this.Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"));
        self.map.setView({
            mapTypeId: self.Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial,
            center: self.map.getCenter(),
            zoom: 15
        });
        this.Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools', function () {
            var tools = new self.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools(self.map);
            var da = self.Microsoft.Maps.DrawingTools.DrawingBarAction;
            const fill = ["rgba(51,0,255,0.2)", "rgba(255,0,0,0.2)", "rgba(255,255,0,0.2)", "rgba(0,204,0,0.2)"]
            const stroke = ["#3300FF", "#FF0000", "#FFFF00", "#00CC00"]
            const lands = localStorage.getItem("lands")
            const parsed = JSON.parse(lands)
            //localStorage
            parsed.forEach(function(e){
               var p = new self.Microsoft.Maps.Polygon(e["polygon"],{
                fillColor: "rgba(51,0,255,0.2)",
                strokeColor: "#3300FF",
                strokeThickness: 4
               });
               console.log(p)
               self.map.entities.push(p);
            })
            tools.showDrawingManager(function (manager) {
                manager.setOptions({
                    drawingBarActions: da.polygon | da.erase,
                    fillColor: "rgba(255,255,255,0)",
                    strokeColor: "#FFF"
                });

                self.Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(manager, 'drawingStarted', function () { console.log('Drawing started.'); });
                self.Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(manager, 'drawingEnded', function (e) {
                    const index = Math.round(Math.random() * 3)
                    console.log(e.geometry)
                    self.setState({
                        polygon: e.geometry,
                        color: stroke[index],
                        fillColor: fill[index],
                        showModal: true
                    })


                });
                self.Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(manager, 'drawingErased', function () { console.log('Drawing erased.'); });
            })
        })

    })
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: o.crossesInternationalDateLine is not a function
    renderGroup https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/hjlBpG0-VvfbKA8YMoC4uh1cYV8.js?bu=BK8FpwaZBrQF:1
    render https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/hjlBpG0-VvfbKA8YMoC4uh1cYV8.js?bu=BK8FpwaZBrQF:1
    _renderVectorTemplates https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
    _renderPrimitives https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
    _renderInternal https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
    render https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
    _finishRenderVectorData https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
    _startRenderVectorData https://www.bing.com/rb/3A/cj,nj/uTdLXSRz12BwM8hu_cTZFExXTP8.js?bu=BK8F8AX3BbQF:1
```

Comment: Why do you tag this with [tag:google-maps] if it is about [tag:bing-maps]?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are serializing the Microsoft.Maps.Polygon instance. The shapes in Bing Maps are classes that have a number of functions on them and aren't designed to be serialized/deserialized as a JSON object. When deserialized none of the functions would exist and you would run into the issues you reported above. An easy solution would be to convert the polygon instance into a serializable JSON or string object such as GeoJSON or Well Known Text.

To do this using GeoJSON, load one of the following Bing Maps modules when your app starts.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson');
```

Then when you want to convert the polygon to a serializable object, "write" it like this:

```
self.setState({
    polygon: Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.write(e),
    color: stroke[index],
    fillColor: fill[index],
    showModal: true
})
```

Then when you go to deserialize it, read it.

```
const lands = localStorage.getItem("lands")
const parsed = JSON.parse(lands)
//localStorage
parsed.forEach(function(e){
   var p = Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.read(e["polygon"],{ polygonOptions: {
    fillColor: "rgba(51,0,255,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "#3300FF",
    strokeThickness: 4
   }});
   console.log(p)
   self.map.entities.push(p);
})
```

Here are some live samples:

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/geojsonwritetogeojson

https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/geojsonreadobject